# Can two transformers used to make tesla coils?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, inductance

Tesla coils seem to perform the same as a transformers: they use two coils and use magnetic field to transfer the energy. Doesn't using two transformers produce the same result? It doesn't seem to be the case as no tutorials talk about this. So can two transformers used to make tesla coils? If not why?

Answer (score 2):

I already got the answer. 
because transformers simply doesn't work in high voltage environments. High voltage environments causes dielectric breakdown which reduce the transformers function which is bad. Tesla coils fix this problem.